Same Twilio phone number showing up in a different format on mobile
Receiving SMS messages from Twilio shows the Twilio phone number as E.164 format: "+1 (111) 111-1111" while receiving MMS messages from Twilio shows the Twilio phone number as this format: "1111111111".
I don't get why Media messages are getting sent from a "1111111111" format while regular text messages are in "+1 (111) 111-1111" format. My snippet for this is as simple as this:
if message_type == 1:
    send_message = messages.create(
        body=message_content,
        from_="+1" + twilio_phone_number,
        to="+1" + recipient_phone_number,
        status_callback=webhook_url,
    )
elif message_type == 2:
    send_message = messages.create(
        media_url=[mms_content],
        from_="+1" + twilio_phone_number,
        to="+1" + recipient_phone_number,
        status_callback=webhook_url,
    )

Yes, I store the phone numbers as "1111111111" in the database, and adding the +1 didn't fix anything.

This seems like a question for Twilio support, not something Stack Overflow can help you with.

The number that appears on the mobile device is associated with how the telephone operator will treat this CallerID. Unfortunately, this is not within Twilio's control.
In cases of calls, there are third-party services that can get around this, which we call branded calls, like the case of GoSat, but there are still no similar services for mms services.
Hope this helps
